# Layout scrolling up when view pager moves to new page

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a layout that contains a viewpager (on the top of the layout) and a listview(Below the pager), and I'm moving to new pages every 3 seconds using the Runnable class, the problem is whenever the pager moves to newpage the layout scrolls up so that I can see the pager. I want to prevent scrolling up and keep the position wherever I'm.

```
pageAdapter = new PagerAdapterCustom(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                getApplicationContext(), pics, true, false);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicatorDetailsNews);

        mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                currentPage = arg0;
                //mIndicator.setCurrentItem(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //mIndicator.setCurrentItem(arg0);
            }
        });

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES - 1) {
                    currentPage = -1;
                }
                pager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                mIndicator.setCurrentItem(currentPage++);
                pager.setScrollBarFadeDuration(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_fillColor);
                // pager.setScrollDurationFactor(4);
            }
        };

        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 1000, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knossos answer is the way, you should manage this from your container Activity,

Let's suppose you're using a RecyclerView, whenever you detect your RecyclerView is scrolled, warn your Activity, you can do something like:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            scrolledValue = dy;

        }
    });
```

and send right back the scrolledValue to the ContainerActivity. ContanierActivity will then notify all the other Fragments about the change and scroll their RecyclerViews by scrolledValue, whether it's a positive or a negative value.

For this I think you can use smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy), but I didn't try it yet. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#smoothScrollBy(int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `Fragment` inside your `PagerAdapterCustom` have no idea of the scrolling state of its' sibling `Fragment`s.

So when you scroll one, the others will of course still be at the top.

To fix this, you need to do two things.

1. When scrolling inside a `Fragment` is detected, you report that scrolling back to the owner of the `PagerAdapterCustom`.
2. When you switch to a new `Fragment`, you report the current scrolling state to the new `Fragment`.